# Filebeat.prospectors: input_type vs type

Tags: filebeat

I've got a couple of filebeat.yml files on different servers.

One has:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
```

and the other has:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
```

Are `input_type` and `type` synonymous?

Answer (score 3):

The `input_type` configuration was renamed to `type` in version 6. It sounds like `input_type` will still work, but moving forward it's recommended to use `type`.

Further details can be found in the docs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/6.1/breaking-changes-6.0.html#breaking-changes-types